# PHP Files work in one setup but not in another

Tags: php, apache, oracle11g, fedora

I've recently made a new Fedora setup, consisting of Fedora 19, Oracle 11g, Apache 2.4.6, and PHP 5.5.4 (afaik). My objective is to migrate an existing PHP setup from one aging PC to this new one. As far as I know, I have everything correct, sans PEAR*.

Now, I've been able to create an info.php page with the following line of code:

```
<?PHP
 phpinfo();
?>
```

That page works fine. (localhost/info.php)

Upon copying over my folder (full of PHP stuff), and trying to access it (via: localhost/hrweb/login.php), all I get is **Internal Error in Server**.

It should be noted that said webpages work fine on the other setup.

I'm not sure how to proceed. Can anyone suggest where else I could look to solve this? Could there be a setting somewhere I missed?

I'm using Konqueror, if that means anything, as it comes by default on Fedora 19.

*- I've seen instances of the webpage running fine (at least, the Log In Page) on a system without PEAR - which I'm not familiar with - so I'm not sure if the lack of PEAR is causing this issue. At the very least, it should display the Log In Page.

Additional Info:

- The entire folder has been set to permissions 775, and the owner:group set to apache:apache

Comment: Take a look in your server logs (/etc/httpd/logs - look for something like 'error_log') - that should give you the cause of the Internal server error, and an idea how to fix things.

Comment: What does `php -r "phpinfo();"` do from the command line?

Comment: @geomagas, the `php -r "phpingo();"` produces a long list of system and PHP information such as directories, configuration, support, variables, environments, a license, along with the occasional warning such as do not rely on system date.

Comment: Have you tried just renaming *.htaccess*, and see if the server would run?

Comment: @MikeW, thanks for the tip on the error_log. Never even knew it was there. There are plenty of errors, but this is the first one:  
`PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/hrweb/login.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0`  
So I'm guessing PEAR does have something to do with it; what would be best, to ask another question about this, or to modify my existing question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Error 500 - Internal server error***

Is an error message, when a user tries to access your *Apache* based dynamic *PHP* application.

To solve this problem you need to take help of log files located at following location:

- /var/log/message
- /var/log/httpd/error_logs

This error only occurs because of web server software. However after looking through logs you may not find many details. This problem may be caused by:

- An invalid directive in an *.htaccess* or other config file
- A malformed *PHP CGI* script
- Limitation imposed by file system and server software (for example PHP log file size set to 10Mb)
- Missing *php.ini* (or cannot read php.ini file)

---

**Most likely you don't have all necessary Apache modules installed. See you `.htaccess` and make sure that Apache has all modules installed required by your software and your Apache new configuration.**

Depending on your server configuration and Apache version you're using, you can basically check it running with `-M` switch:

```
httpd -M
```

It will tell you which modules are *built-in* or *shared* that you have.

If you're running *PHP* as `mod_php` then you could also check Apache avalable modules running:

```
print_r( apache_get_modules() );
```

---

- In addition:

  1. Check that you have correct *file paths* set, with `require/include` directives;
  2. Check that you have correct *folders/files permissions*,  To debug the problem, run inside of your home directory: `ls -lsa`. After you will be able to see the *owner/group* settings. In case it's incorrect, you could fix it by running: `chown -R correctOwner:correctGroup *`

Comment: Is there a way to 'compare notes', of sorts, between what Apache modules are installed in the older Fedora setup, to the ones that are installed in the new Fedora setup? A command for the CLI, perhaps?

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer. You should use `httpd -M`.